# Add property chain to JS Object

Tags: javascript, object

Is it possible in one line to add a property to an added property of an added property of ...

```
var some_object = {};
some_object.prop_a = "hi";
some_object.prop_b.prop_c.prop_d = "ho";
```

while line 2 obviously works, line 3 doesnt as it returns the `cannot read property of undefined` error. I know, that prop_b and prop_c dont exist when prop_d should be assigned. But is there a simple one-liner to do what i want to do (i.e. add a nested property even if some levels in the nested object dont exist yet)?

Comment: No, there isn't. You must define the objects you're writing to.

Comment: Out of the box, no, but you could certainly write a function that would take a chain of properties and an object and add empty objects as needed.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37437805/convert-map-to-json-object-in-javascript/37438729?noredirect=1#comment62398771_37438729.

Comment: hopefully coming soon to more browsers! This could be achieved using a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could certainly write a function to do this. Something like this perhaps:

```js
function addPropertyChain(chain, val, obj) {
    var propChain = chain.split(".");
    if (propChain.length === 1) {
        obj[propChain[0]] = val;
        return;
    }
    var first = propChain.shift();
    if (!obj[first]) {
        obj[first] = {};
    }    
    addPropertyChain(propChain.join("."), val, obj[first] );
}

var some_object = {};
addPropertyChain("prop_b.prop_c.prop_d","ho",some_object);

console.log(some_object);
```

Comment: I think we had the same thoughts about this problem. good job.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Thought about writing a function myself if there is no other way. Yours is pretty handy and will be used!

Answer (score 3):

> I know, that prop_b and prop_c dont exist when prop_d should be assigned.

If this is the case, you can do this:

```
some_object.prop_b = {
  prop_c : {
    prop_d : "ho"
  }
};
```

(Or, in one line:)

```
some_object.prop_b = { prop_c : { prop_d : "ho" } };
```

You're just using JavaScript's [object initializer syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) to create nested objects.

However, beware as this would overwrite any existing `prop_b` or `prop_b.prop_c` values, if those values already existed.

Comment: Thought about that too, but as you already pointed out it would overwrite.

Answer (score 0):

You could call a method to ensure the slot is an object before assigning. A disadvantage is that you have supply the path as a string. You'd have to walk the chain.

```
function ensurePropertyOnObject(o, m)
{
    var props = m.split('.');
    var item;
    var current = o;

    while(item = props.shift()) {
        if(typeof o[item] != 'object') {
            current[item] = {};
        }
        current = o[item];
    }    
}

ensurePropertyOnObject(some_object, "prop_b.prop_c.prop_d");
some_object.prop_b.prop_c.prop_d = "ho";
console.log(some_object);
```

See an example: https://jsfiddle.net/ho4k02fr/

Answer (score 0):

To dynamically access and set object properties i had invented two Object methods called `Object.prototype.setNestedValue()` and `Object.prototype.getNestedValue()` In which you provide the nested properties as arguments. For the `Object.prototype.setNestedValue()` the last argument is the value to be set at the end. Goes like this;

```js
Object.prototype.getNestedValue = function(...a) {
  return a.length > 1 ? (this[a[0]] !== void 0 && this[a[0]].getNestedValue(...a.slice(1))) : this[a[0]];
};

Object.prototype.setNestedValue = function(...a) {
  return a.length > 2 ? typeof this[a[0]] === "object" && this[a[0]] !== null ? this[a[0]].setNestedValue(...a.slice(1))
                                                                              : (this[a[0]] = typeof a[1] === "string" ? {} : new Array(a[1]),
                                                                                 this[a[0]].setNestedValue(...a.slice(1)))
                      : this[a[0]] = a[1];
};

var some_object = {};
some_object.prop_a = "hi";
some_object.setNestedValue("prop_b","prop_c","prop_d","ho");
console.log(JSON.stringify(some_object,null,2));
```

You can also add array objects. For that you have to enter the index in number type though. Lets have an example...

```js
Object.prototype.getNestedValue = function(...a) {
  return a.length > 1 ? (this[a[0]] !== void 0 && this[a[0]].getNestedValue(...a.slice(1))) : this[a[0]];
};

Object.prototype.setNestedValue = function(...a) {
  return a.length > 2 ? typeof this[a[0]] === "object" && this[a[0]] !== null ? this[a[0]].setNestedValue(...a.slice(1))
                                                                              : (this[a[0]] = typeof a[1] === "string" ? {} : new Array(a[1]),
                                                                                 this[a[0]].setNestedValue(...a.slice(1)))
                      : this[a[0]] = a[1];
};

var some_object = {};
some_object.prop_a = "hi";
some_object.setNestedValue("prop_b",3,"prop_d","yay");
some_object.setNestedValue("prop_b",0,"prop_d","zero this is");
some_object.setNestedValue("prop_b",1,"prop_d","i am the one");
some_object.setNestedValue("prop_b","prop_c","prop_d","ho");
console.log(JSON.stringify(some_object,null,2));
```

You will notice that prop_c s not enlisted but that still exists as a property of the array assigned to prob_b and it's fully accessible.