# Converting my Postman Call to Dart/Flutter API Call

Tags: rest, http, flutter, dart, postman

I hope to use nutritionix api to get food information for the users of my application, I manage to get the call to work in Postman, however I cannot convert it to dart code. I am getting this error: '{message: Unexpected token " in JSON at position 0}'

Here is my **(POST)** postman call:

[image: Headers for POST call] [image: Body for POST call]

Here is my attempt at converting that to dart code:

```
  Future<void> fetchNutritionix() async {
    String url = 'https://trackapi.nutritionix.com/v2/natural/nutrients';
    Map<String, String> headers = {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "x-app-id": "5bf----",
      "x-app-key": "c3c528f3a0c68-------------",
      "x-remote-user-id": "0",
    };
    String query = 'query: chicken noodle soup';

    http.Response response =
        await http.post(url, headers: headers, body: query);

    int statusCode = response.statusCode;
    print('This is the statuscode: $statusCode');
    final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
    print(responseJson);

    //print('This is the API response: $responseJson');
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated! And, again thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your postman screenshot shows `x-www-form-urlencoded` as the `content-type`, so why are you changing that to `application/json` in your headers? Remove the content type header (the package will add it for you) and simply pass a map to the body parameter:

```
  var response = await http.post(
    url,
    headers: headers,
    body: {
      'query': 'chicken soup',
      'brand': 'acme',
    },
  );
```

Answer (score 2):

Also you can now generate Dart code (and many other languages) for your Postman request by clicking the `Code` button just below the `Save` button.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

click the three dotes button in request tab and select code option then select your language that you want convert code to

Comment: Thanks for the simple but valuable answer

Answer (score 0):

review the query you're posting

your Postman input is `x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of plain text

```
String query = 'query: chicken noodle soup';
```

why don't you try JSON better

```
String query = '{ "query" : "chicken noodle soup" }';
```

Comment: Woah! After being stuck at this problem for 2 days you fixed it! Thank you so much! I hope you have a great day/evening!

Comment: Hello again @arhak, how do I add another body parameter such as "num_servings" : "1"? I tried creating a map<String, String> but i'm getting an error: 'Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Cannot set the body fields of a Request with content-type "application/json"'

Comment: @AllenAndreIndefenzo although the `headers` is taking in a map, the `body` is not, so you'd need to make it JSON yourself, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44740579/1681985