# Typescript map never updates

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-cloud-firestore

I have this function

```
export class SessionUtilities {  
   public getSessionStatsFromAppStats(sessionStats: SessionStats, appStats: AppStats): SessionStats {

        let updatedStats: SessionStats = {
            occurrences: ++sessionStats.occurrences,
            appVersions: new Map<string, number>([
                ['1.0.0', 1]
            ])
        };

        console.log('Updated stats',JSON.stringify(updatedStats));

        ...
  }
}
```

And when I run my unit test the `appVersions` property is always empty. Here's the console log output.

```
Updated stats {"occurrences":1,"appVersions":{}}
```

I'm completely baffled by what's happening here. I am not a TS developer, but I'm not a beginner engineer either. But here's the weird thing.

The unit test passes when it checks if the appVersion map has the key and the value 1.

So why is the map empty when used?

For some context, I hardcoded the value because when I get this map back and I try to save the map to Firestore it's empty again. So in debug mode, or while it's running the values are all there but when I print it out it's empty again.

I don't know if Maps should be handled in a special way in type script, but it's been 2 hours now and I have no idea why this is happening.

Edit:

I have swapped from `Map<string, number>` to `{ [key: string]: number}` and the code is behaving as expected.

What I'd like to know now is why Map acts that way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/54180342/2358409

Comment: JSON format does not have a built in way to represent `Map` objects.