# Unable to process recursive structure

Tags: typescript, recursion

I have a recursive JSON structure that I want to store as a series of maps with keys. The structure is a series of flows and subflows which can reference each other. Here is a declaration of the types: Plase note that the issue is not with maps.  I use use and store objects in the application in several places as I am using a typescript version that is able to store objects. The algorithm is faulty and that's what is the issue

```
    type Flow = {
       flowId: number,
       subFlows?: Array<SubFlow>
    } 

    type SubFlow = {
      subFlowId: number,
      flow?: Flow,
    }

    type FlowGroup = {
        flows:Map<number,Flow>,
        subFlows:Map<number,Flow>
    }
```

Ultimately, the goal is to store the flow in a flowgroup structure with flowIds as keys
And here is a sample of the JSON:

```
             {
               "flowId": 90112,
               "subFlows": [
                {
                "subFlowId": 52820,
                "flow": {
                   "flowId": 80032,
                   "subFlows": [
                    { 
                      "subFlowId": 76422
                    }, 
                    {
                       "subFlowId": 12654
                    }
                  ]
                    }
                   },
                   {
                      "subFlowId": 12422
                   }
               ]
            }
```

Unfortunately, my attempt to populate this returns an empty flowgroup. Here is my attempt: Here is mainflow :

```
   const mainFlow:Flow = { 
     flowId: 90112,
     subFlows: _subFlows
     }



   
   function processFlow(flow: Flow) {
     if (flow && flow.subFlows === undefined) {
        flowGroup.flows.set(flow.flowId, flow);
     } else if (flow && Array.isArray(flow.subFlows)) {
        for (const subFlow of flow.subFlows) {
            flowGroup.subFlows.set(subFlow.subFlowId, subFlow);
            if (subFlow.flow) {
                processFlow(subFlow.flow);
            }
        }
    }
}

processFlow(mainFlow);
console.log(`FlowGroup is ${JSON.stringify(flowGroup)}`);
```

Here is the data In used to create the test:

```
const subFlow1:SubFlow ={
 subFlowId: 52820
 }

const subFlow2:SubFlow ={
 subFlowId: 12422
}

 const flow3:SubFlow = {
  subFlowId: 76422
 }

 const flow4: SubFlow = {
  subFlowId: 12654
 }

 const flow5: Flow = {
  flowId: 80032,
   subFlows: [flow3, flow4]
 }

subFlow1.flow = flow5;  

 const flowGroup: FlowGroup = {
      flows: new Map<number, Flow>(),
      subFlows: new Map<number, Flow>()
    }



 const _subFlows = [subFlow1, subFlow2];

 const mainFlow:Flow ={
  flowId: 90112,
  subFlows: _subFlows
 }
```

Here is where I print the values of a map set manually: this prints the values on the console

```
    const m = new Map<string, Flow>();
    m.set(flow5.flowId, flow5);
    
    for(const [k, v] of m.entries()){
      console.log(` Map key = ${k} and value = 
             ${JSON.stringify(v)}`);
      }
```

These compiler settings for typescript are able to handle maps: You are assuming i am using es6.

```
   "target": "esNext",
   "module": "es2022",
   "moduleResolution": "node",
```

Please see some code I am using successfully in this app:

```
productHandler<Product, ProductKey
    extends keyof Product>(product: Product, productKey: ProductKey) {
    const map = new Map<ProductKey, Array<string>>();
    const productData = product[productKey] as unknown as Array<string>;
    map.set(productKey, productData)
    return map;
}
```

Comment: Your posted TS doesn't compile: I get an error on the `flowGroup.subFlows.set(subFlow.subFlowId, subFlow);` line: "Argument of type '`SubFlow`' is not assignable to parameter of type '`Flow`'"

Comment: It is the data I created to test

Comment: I added the code. I missed it when posting, sorry about that. I am relatively new to Typescript. If there is better way to do it without the global variable how do I use it?

Comment: It's there,  const mainFlow:Flow ={
  flowId: 90112,
  subFlows: _subFlows
 }
t

Comment: It is there now

Comment: Typescript maps are not native Javascript associative arrays. It appears the JSON lib has no idea how to stringify them. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46066343/convert-typescript-mapstring-string-to-json-string-representation  nb: You might want to ask how to solve the bigger problem. The way you're going about this is very far from idiomatic typescript.

Comment: Not quite, it's the algorithm that seems to be wrong. i am able to store things in the map outside of the algorithm

Comment: const m = new Map<string, Flow>();
m.set(flow5.flowId, flow5);
for(const [k, v] of m.entries()){
    console.log(` Map key = ${k} and value = ${JSON.stringify(v)}`);
}

Comment: Exactly. It can stringify the values. But your original code attempts to do it for the `Map`. That doesn't work. I'm sure the algorithm could be wrong, too. I didn't look at that.

Comment: I use maps in this version of the typescript compiler all over storing keys and objects with no issues. I am using a later version of the compiler as I posted in my tsconfig.

Comment: Okay. Your question is still unclear to me.  The JSON you gave _is_ the structure of `mainFlow:Flow`, which is the input to your algorithm.  What do you expect as output?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247070/discussion-between-breendeen-and-gene).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I see what you're attempting to do. It would be clearer if you described inputs **and outputs** with an example.

The simplest way to handle recursive processing of a structure with N node types is with a set of N mutually recursive functions. Something like this:

```
type Flow = {
  flowId: number,
  subFlows?: Array<SubFlow>
} 

type SubFlow = {
  subFlowId: number,
  flow?: Flow,
}

type FlowGroup = {
  flows: Map<number,Flow>,
  subFlows: Map<number,Flow>
}
    
const subFlow1:SubFlow = {
  subFlowId: 52820
}

const subFlow2:SubFlow = {
  subFlowId: 12422
}

const flow3:SubFlow = {
  subFlowId: 76422
}

const flow4: SubFlow = {
  subFlowId: 12654
}

const flow5: Flow = {
  flowId: 80032,
  subFlows: [flow3, flow4]
}

subFlow1.flow = flow5;  

const _subFlows = [subFlow1, subFlow2];

const mainFlow: Flow = {
  flowId: 90112,
  subFlows: _subFlows
}

const flowGroup: FlowGroup = {
  flows: new Map<number, Flow>(),
  subFlows: new Map<number, Flow>()
}

function accumulateFlow(flow: Flow) {
  if (flow == null) {
    return;
  }
  flowGroup.flows.set(flow.flowId, flow);
  for (let subFlow of flow.subFlows) {
    accumulateSubflow(subFlow);
  }
}

function accumulateSubflow(subFlow: SubFlow) {
  flowGroup.subFlows.set(subFlow.subFlowId, subFlow);
  accumulateFlow(subFlow.flow);
}

accumulateFlow(mainFlow)
console.log('Flows ' + JSON.stringify(Array.from(flowGroup.flows.keys())))
console.log('SubFlows ' + JSON.stringify(Array.from(flowGroup.subFlows.keys())))
```

This produces

```
"Flows [90112,80032]"
"SubFlows [52820,76422,12654,12422]"
```

Either this is correct or I still misunderstand the problem.

In this case, `accumulateSubflow` is simple and only called once. So you could choose to inline it.

```
function accumulateFlow(flow: Flow) {
  if (flow == null) {
    return;
  }
  flowGroup.flows.set(flow.flowId, flow)
  for (let subFlow of flow.subFlows) {
    flowGroup.subFlows.set(subFlow.subFlowId, subFlow)
    accumulateFlow(subFlow.flow)
  }
}
```

The downside here is that if you ever have a structure where the root is a sub-flow rather than a flow, you're out of luck. With two functions, covering more cases in the future requires less thinking.

Comment: The final object is called a FlowGroup, it holds 2 maps,  one for the flows and another for the subFlows.  The flows should be stored in the Flowgroup map by flowId, and the SubFlows by subFlowId

Comment: That's exactly what the code above does. @BreenDeen