# POST request with nested Map empty

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, typescript, fetch

I have a springboot application with a React/Typescript frontend. I current have the following two interfaces and an object created out of such.

```
export interface Order {
    customer_id: number;
    date: Date;
    total: number;
    spec: OrderSpec;
}

export interface OrderSpec {
    order: Map<number, number>
}
```

I construct an object of type Order and try to create a post request using it as follows:

```
return fetch(url, {
    method: method,
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(item),
});
```

My problem is that every time a request is sent the object looks like:
[the order map is always empty (see... spec:{order:{}})](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dA2Z.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you stringify a `Map`, you get an empty json object.

Either you convert your `Map` into an `object` and then post it to your api or simply change your data structure/types to store object.

you can use the code below to convert your map into js object

```js
 let myMap = new Map();
 myMap.set(1, 'one');
 myMap.set(2, 'two');

 Object.assign({}, ...Array.from(myMap.entries()).map(([k, v]) =>({[k]: v}) ))
```

Refer below for more guidance on Map conversion:

[Convert Map to JSON object in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37437805/convert-map-to-json-object-in-javascript)

https://gist.github.com/lukehorvat/133e2293ba6ae96a35ba