# Convert Map/String to JSON

Tags: java, jackson

If I have a map like this

```
{"media.video.one"="hello", "media.video.two"="world", "media.audio.one"="hi"}

or 

{"/media/video/one"="hello", "/media/video/two"="world", "/media/audio/one"="hi"}
```

Is it possible to convert this into JSON using Jackson and ObjectMapper APIs like this?

```
{
  "media": {
    "video": {
      "one": "hello",
      "two": "hello"
    },
    "auido": {
      "one": "hi"
    }
  }
}
```

Or how I can do this in code?

I found something similar in JS here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37438096/6024354

Comment: What does your map actually look like? Is it a `Map<String, String>`? If so, why does it have such a flat structure when the json you want seems to require some deeper nesting? And finally, if it is a `Map<String, String>` I'd suggest you split the keys at the dots and build a bunch of nested maps with the appropriate key part at each level.

Comment: The map is of type Map<String, String>. I'm getting this map from a different source and I basically need to convert it to JSON.  The objectmapper.readTree() api works similarly in the other directtion. I was curious to see if this way was possible.

Comment: Well, `readTree()` returns a bunch of nested maps, i.e. every JSON object is represented as a map and since you have 4 objects (the main one, "media", "video" and "audio") you'd get 4 maps. Serializing those maps or a similarly built structure would be supported by Jackson but I'm not sure a flat `Map<String, String>` would be produced or consumed in the way you want - at least not out-of-the-box.

Comment: I found something similar in JS here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37438096/6024354

Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: That basically looks like what I was suggesting - and it wouldn't be that complex. Any more generic approach would probably be more complex.