# Cypress: can't pass a map as mocked rest call response

Tags: typescript, mocking, cypress, ecmascript-5

I'm trying to mock a rest call in Cypress. This rest call should return a map as response, e.g.:

```
cy.intercept('POST', 'path', new Map([['a', 'abc']])
```

The problem is that this will return an empty object instead of the expected map.

To make it work, I have to write the map like:

```
 cy.intercept('POST', 'path', {a: 'abc'})
```

Note: I'm using TS and, inside its configuration file, I have `target: es5` and `"lib": ["esnext"]`

Comment: What's the structure of the call normally? Is it a map, or is it a JSON-object that resembles a Map's data structure?

Comment: It's an object containing a map. <MyObject>{ myMap: Map}

Answer (score 2):

HTTP POST does not support the Javascript Map object as a response, but you can convert on the fly in your test.

Please see [Convert Map to JavaScript object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55537385/16997707), in your test

```js
cy.intercept('POST', 'path', Object.fromEntries(new Map([['a', 'abc']]))
```